# How to send encoded KMS keyring information in google signed URL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, encryption, pre-signed-url, google-cloud-kms

How to send KMS  keyring information in encoded format in google signed URL for customer managed encryption key

I have added "x-goog-encryption-kms-key-name": "projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/us/keyRings/{KEYRING_NAME}/cryptoKeys/{KEY_VERSION}"

But looks like we are exposing lot of confidential information in keyring . Is it possible to encode this and send.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the confidential information? the project ID, the keyring name and the key version?

Comment: Yes . I don't want to expose  those information to enduser